# BringToFront() does not work with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I need to bring an ImageView up above all the layouts to show that it is overlapping to the TextView. Unluckily, none of what I've tried from SO helped me. This is what's happening.

[image]

> main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Students"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fraLayout1"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgKOala"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/koala" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> main.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imgKOala = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgKOala);
    imgKOala.bringToFront();
    imgKOala.invalidate();
    imgKOala.requestLayout();
    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(imgKOala, 1000);

}
```

How can I properly make the ImageView appear above the TextView Students?
This is only a representation of what I really want to achieve.

Comment: you want to keep imageview on top of all your views right ?

Comment: Why are you calling invalidate after bringToFront?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Students"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgKOala"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I really need the ImageView to be deeper than the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Set an elevation on the `ImageView`. `2dp` seems to work.

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

**Hope this helped!**

Answer (score 0):

The `bringToFront` and Z-order of views are all related to the view's parent view, so if you call `bringToFront` on your `imgKOala`, it just **at the front of** its parent view `fraLayout1`. If you want `imgKOala` overlap the `TextView`, you should evaluate the `FrameLayout` which is sibling to the `TextView`.

In you layout file, your `FrameLayout` have the property:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle"
```

and `ImageView`:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
```

so your ImageView is not fully displayed, because the top 55dp of it is outside of its parent.

Try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Students"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fraLayout1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgKOala"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/koala" />

            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

just set `android:elevation=2dp` on the FrameLayout which is sibling to the TextView, and the code in your `onCreate()` method can be removed.