# Android studio - Xml, item conflict problem

Tags: android, xml

[image: My app menu]

If you look to my app menu the add button is behind the to do list. But i want the opposite. "To do Lists" button is a button and has a background image. Add button is a ImageButton. I tried change the order of items like this:

[image: Tried one]

[image: Tried two]

This is what i want:

[image: This is what i want]

Xml codes (id: btnList | id: btnAdd):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="75dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="75dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.43" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_sign"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_sign"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="To Do Lists"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSettings" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:onClick="addSomething"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectang" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:onClick="addSomething"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus_sign" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fMainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include xml code

Comment: I thought like not to add because of code is busy but okay I'm gonna add.

Comment: why do you use Guideline?

Comment: Because of supporting different device size with percentage scale.

Comment: And sorry about my English. And I'm new on Kotlin, trying something :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your `btnList`, replace this one

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
```

with this

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAdd"
```

Updated:

So I think you want to make the button + inside the circle centered.

So, moved the btnAdd and btnAdd2 inside a RelativeLayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd2"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to list button and add button side by side. Add button is a circle so list button should be behind of circle. So i don't want this: <https://i.snipboard.io/YkazPg.jpg>

guideline8 is inside of add circle.

Comment: you want to change only the `+` button ? @Emre . I updated the answer

Comment: Yes, i just want to make "+ button" front of "list button."

Comment: Nooo, i guess i have very bad English :). You see the "To Do Lists" button in picture right. And plus sign. But in there "To Do Lists" button is front of the plus sign. But i want to "Plus sign" is should be front of "To Do Lists" button.

Comment: I paint this : <https://i.snipboard.io/8T6zLC.jpg> @Ticherhaz

Comment: @Emre yes, I noticed about that. There is another way which is using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136144/bringtofront-does-not-work-with-constraintlayout

Comment: np. glad to help